# UNIX c programming

Tags: c++, c, linux, unix, operating-system

Can anybody tell me how you would do this question ?

Write short C program for a UNIX/Linux operating system that will do the following:

- Fork a child process
- The parent process  prints out its own pid and its child’s pid
- The parent exits properly so as not to orphan its child
- The child process sets its own priority to 2
- The child process prints out its own pid, its parent’s pid and its own priority
- The child process checks if it is an orphan before finishing; if it is an orphan it prints a message to say “I am an orphan”.

You do not need to put any error checks in your program. You do not need to list all of the C library include files, i.e. the .h files.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because SO is not a code-writing service.

Comment: I need to know how to do it for tomorrow and have no clue :(

Comment: But show your effort first

Comment: I'd start with `man fork`.

Comment: Here is some reference material to get you started:

> Fork a child process 

See http://linux.die.net/man/2/fork

> The parent process prints out its own pid and its
> child’s pid

Use the return value from ```fork(2)``` and see http://linux.die.net/man/2/getpid

> The child process sets its own priority to 2

See http://linux.die.net/man/2/nice

> The child process prints out its own pid, its parent’s pid and its own priority

See http://linux.die.net/man/2/getpid and http://linux.die.net/man/2/getppid

Comment: `fork();
getpid();
printf("Childs pid is %d" \n);
exit(0);
nice(8);
getppid;
printf("Parents pid is %d" \n);`
????

Answer (score 2):

Since stack overflow is by NO means a write code for me please website the only "answer" we can offer you is a suggestion on where to look. With that in mind look up pthreads. Beyond that I don't expect people to give you anything due dates are your problem not ours.

Comment: `fork();
getpid();
printf("Childs pid is %d" \n);
exit(0);
nice(8);
getppid;
printf("Parents pid is %d" \n);`
????